# Alternative to using IList.Contains(item.Id) in Entity Framework for large lists?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there an alternative to using `.Contains()` to select objects in Entity Framework that exist in a specified list? `Contains()` works great if your list is small, however once you start getting a few thousands items the performance is terrible.

```
return (from item in context.Accounts
        where accountIdList.Contains(item.AccountId)
        select item).ToList();
```

I'm using EF 4.0, .Net Framework 4.0, and SQL Server 2005. I'm not opposed to a SQL solution either since the query that EF generates only takes a second to run on SQL for about 10k items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative that runs in about a second using a SQL Stored Procedure and a comma-delimited string for the parameter. Much better than the 5+ minutes EF was taking using `.Contains()`

It is run from my code using the following:

```
string commaDelmitedList = string.Join(",", accountIdList);
return context.GetAccountsByList(commaDelmitedList).ToList();
```

The StoredProcedure (simplified) looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Accounts as T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Num FROM dbo.StringToNumSet(@commaDelimitedAccountIds, ',')
) as [T2] ON [T1].[AccountId] = [T2].[num]
```

And the User-Defined function `dbo.StringToNumSet()` looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StringToNumSet] (
 @TargetString  varchar(MAX),
 @SearchChar varchar(1)
 )
RETURNS @Set TABLE (
 num int not null
 )
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @SearchCharPos  int,  @LastSearchCharPos int
 SET @SearchCharPos = 0
 WHILE 1=1
 BEGIN
  SET @LastSearchCharPos = @SearchCharPos
  SET @SearchCharPos = CHARINDEX( @SearchChar, @TargetString, @SearchCharPos + 1 )
  IF @SearchCharPos = 0
  BEGIN
   INSERT @Set( num ) VALUES ( SUBSTRING( @TargetString, @LastSearchCharPos + 1, DATALENGTH( @TargetString ) ) )
   BREAK
  END
  ELSE
   INSERT @Set( num ) VALUES ( SUBSTRING( @TargetString, @LastSearchCharPos + 1, @SearchCharPos - @LastSearchCharPos - 1 ) )
 END
 RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be viable to just read you infomation into memory then do the searchs.

I've found that in most cases were you need to work with big amounts of data if you can get away with reading all the data into memory and then doing the lookups its much much faster.

Comment: Nope, the database has a few million accounts and the data I want from the database includes a couple of joins which makes the end result set even bigger

Comment: @Rachel, have you tried using a profiler to see what queries are being generated. http://efprof.com/ has a free trail and could help with this.

Comment: Yes I have and the query runs fine. It takes about a second to pull about 10k records out of a few million. The part I find unacceptable is that EF takes about 5 minutes to generate the SQL statement using .Contains() on a list of about 10k items.

Comment: @Rachel, you can pre compile the queries, then they should run faster. Aslo take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739461/how-to-reduce-entity-framework-4-query-compile-time link. Here is a http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-pre-compiled-linq-to-entities-queries-in-web-apps-and-services/ link for how to run pre compiled Queries.

Comment: I'm not sure that pre-compiled queries will help since it is not the Query creating the problem - it is the 10k item list in the `.Contains()` that is causing the slowdown

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` already gets translated to to a massive `WHERE IN` SQL statement, so that's not really a problem. However, you shouldn't eagerly evaluate the query, as this will execute the query everytime you call that method. Take advantage of the the nature of linq-to-entities and let the query get evaluated when you actually iterate over it.

Comment: Can you post some code showing an example? I'm still fairly new to linq-to-entities. Also, the SQL statement performance is fine (about a second to process), it's building the SQL statement that is taking EF so long.

Comment: Hm, okay. Removing the `ToList` would be the example. Though I can understand it can take some time. Would it be possible to keep the `accountIdList` in database somehow? You could then use a simple join instead of an autogenerated `WHERE IN` clause.

Comment: The `accountIdList` is based on user input, so no. It can be read from an excel file of accountIds, or it is generated based on other user input such sales batch, payment batch, etc