# GetExecutionPlan and EnsureConnection causing really slow performance for EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework to look up (and save) an entity in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  My problem is with a simple `ObjectContext.FirstOrDefault` call (though it is abstracted via an IRepository pattern).

I am noticing really really poor performance.  So attached a profiler and found that the first query I run is where most of the slow downs are.

So the first thing I thought was that I have a bad index.  But running a lookup in SSMS is nearly instantaneous.  (That is not the problem.)  Also tried switching the first query I call and the performance hit stayed mostly with the first query.

There are two methods that EF is calling that take a high percentage of my run time.  They are GetExecutionPlan and EnsureConnection.

Are these just overhead that I have to deal with if I want to use EF?  Or is there a way to optimize these calls?

One thing I thought of is re-using my Entity Framework ObjectContext.  I think if I did that then some of the slow downs would be overcome by caching.  However, I have read bad things about reusing the ObjectContext (which is why I was making a new one with each of my service calls).

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739461/how-to-reduce-entity-framework-4-query-compile-time)